# How to open System Profiler.app on Mac OS X using a Java application?

Tags: java, macos, runtime

I have to show system information for my Mac OS X from my Java application.

I have created a button and trying to execute following:

```
private static String[] sysInfoPathMac =
    {"/usr/bin/open", "'/Applications/Utilities/System Profiler.app'"};
```

In the click event of the button I execute following command:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sysInfoPathMac);
```

I am not getting anything once button is clicked. It does not throw any error and neither does it run the system profiler.

What exactly I am doing wrong and how to get it done?

Comment: Maybe escape the space like so: `"System\\ Profiler.app"`

Comment: tried doing that but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single-quotes. When you run the command from the shell the quotes are needed because the argument has a space in it. This isn't an issue when starting the process from Java because each element of the array is treated as a separate argument regardless of whether it contains spaces.

```
String[] command = {"/usr/bin/open", "/Applications/Utilities/System Profiler.app"};
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
int resultCode = proc.waitFor();
if (resultCode != 0) {
    throw new Exception("failed to open system profiler");
}
```

Note that in general when using Runtime.exec() you'll want to consume the stdout and stderr streams to avoid deadlock (although in this case it's not an issue since the 'open' command doesn't produce much output). For more on the subject check out Michael C. Daconta's article "When Runtime.exec() Won't"
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html