# Open applications with Runtime.exec() on OS X

Tags: java, macos, process, runtime.exec

How to open applications with Runtime.exec() on OS X?

my instructor did give us an example of how to do it, except the only problem is that he uses Windows while I use Mac OS X, here is the code that I have customized so far:

```
public class Runtime_execution{
public static void main(String args[]){
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc;
    try{
        if(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS X")){
//                run an OS specific program
            proc = rt.exec("Contacts");
        }else{
            proc = rt.exec("gedit");
        }
        System.out.println("Before calling waitFor() method.");
        proc.waitFor(); //  try removing this line
        System.out.println("After calling waitFor() method.");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Contacts is an unknown command.");
    }
}
}
// find out what the os name is for Mac OS X
class Random{
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("os.name"));
}
}
```

When I ran the program, the output kept displaying:

```
Contacts is an unknown command.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Read (and implement) *all* the recommendations of [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html).  That might solve the problem.  If not, it should provide more information as to the reason it failed.  Then ignore that it refers to `exec` and build the `Process` using a `ProcessBuilder`.  Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for arguments which themselves contain spaces.

Comment: Also, make sure the command you are trying to run actually works! Try running the command from Terminal. For example, typing `Contacts` in Terminal reports: `command not found`. However, `open /Application/Contacts.app` will open the Mac Contacts application.

Comment: This is a legitimate question. It is not an exact duplicate of any other thread, nor is it "not a real question" - the OP has provided proper code snippet and proper error messages. Nothing in the question is vague. If you can - try to help answering the question. But closing this question is wrong. I think @Devon_C_Miller comment partially answers the question, can you please post it as an answer instead...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open System Profiler.app on Mac OS X using a Java application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477949/how-to-open-system-profiler-app-on-mac-os-x-using-a-java-application)

Comment: I will never understand why so many useful questions are closed by some "i-am-very-wise-and-smart" people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OSX you need to run the executable via command line which is what Runtime.exec is doing.

Try this:

```
rt.exec("/Applications/Contacts.app/Contents/MacOS/Contacts");
```

or you can do a

```
rt.exec("open /Applications/Contacts.app");
```

Comment: worked with `open -n` instead of only `open`